# How do I inspect an element with Cypress 3.1.4?

Tags: cypress

In the previous versions of Cypress, you could right-click on an element in the browser, select Inspect, and see the HTML of the element you were pointing to.
That has all disappeared.
How am I meant to find these now?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing `cmd+shift+c` as that is the shortcut for chrome-dev-tools element selector.

Also try pressing `F12` to bring up devtools, and clicking the select element button in the top left corner:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Open Selector Playground` button next to url address.

[image]

-----Edited----

Also you have to change browser from electron to chromium (right top corner)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can see the Open Selector Playground, but it doesn't help me. The Inspect command formerly displayed the HTML in the Console window.

Comment: I added it to my answer, please check edited section.

Comment: Yep. I had to do that too. It didn't work at all in the Chromium option. I still can't Inspect the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I re-installed chrome and that fixed my issue. I actually had to download chrome and re-install it, not just upgrade.

Comment: I re-installed Chrome. I still cannot right click & inspect an element.

Comment: Well that sucks. I forget do you get the drop down to change the browser to Chrome 71 (or some other number). Or does it say chromium?